# wp-load Without Loading the plugins

Tags: php, wp-load.php

I am building a 'control panel', for my server and would like to use my Wordpress userbase to control the login functionality, as well as be able to show some posts.

I have set some defines and included wp-load:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', false );
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
// define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
include( '/home/getyou/www/wp-load.php' );
```

With `shortinit` defined, I am able to utilize some of the functionality, however the `user` functionality fails, without it, I notice my w3 Total Cache is caching everything.

Is there a way I can continue to use all of the wordpress functionality, but possibly unload or disable w3 total cache for this external site?

EDIT

Added a `mu-plugin` with the following code to disable all plugins based on defining `MEDINIT`

```
if ( defined( 'MEDINIT ') && MEDINIT ) {
    add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function ( $plugins ) {
        $plug_arr = get_plugins();
        foreach( $plug_arr as $k => $v){
            unset( $plugins[$k] );
        }
        return $plugins;
    } );
}
```

However, when I call `var_dump( get_option('active_plugins') );` it still loads all plugins.

Comment: Something strange.   When I implement the `var_dump` in my external file, the W3 Total Cache comment at the bottom of the source code dissappears, but when I get rid of the `var_dump` it reappears...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to put something like this in a .php file of any name in your must-use plugins folder (`/wp-content/mu-plugins/`) so that it loads before all plugins so you can use it to filter the plugin loading...

```
<?php 
if (defined('SHORTINIT') && SHORTINIT) {
    add_filter('option_active_plugins', 'shortinit_plugins_filter');
    function shortinit_plugins_filter($plugins) {
        $noloadplugins = array('w3-total-cache');
        foreach ($plugins as $i => $plugin) {
             if (in_array($plugin, $noloadplugins)) {unset($plugins[$i]);}
        }
        return $plugins;
    }
}
```

Alternatively manually include whatever function files you need to make things work as they should.

**UPDATE for Multisite**

You would need to use a different filter on multisite, something like this should work, eg. for blog ID 2...

```
<?php 
if (defined('SHORTINIT') && SHORTINIT) {
    add_filter('site_option_active_plugins', 'shortinit_site_plugins_filter', 10, 3);
    function shortinit_site_plugins_filter($plugins, $option, $network_id) {
        if ($network_id == 2) {
            $noloadplugins = array('w3-total-cache');
            foreach ($plugins as $i => $plugin) {
                 if (in_array($plugin, $noloadplugins)) {unset($plugins[$i]);}
            }
        }
        return $plugins;
    }
}
```

Note if wanted to change sitewide activated plugins you would need to do further filtering of the network wide active plugins, something like:

```
<?php 
if (defined('SHORTINIT') && SHORTINIT) {
    add_filter('option_active_sitewide_plugins', 'shortinit_network_plugins_filter');
    function shortinit_network_plugins_filter($plugins) {
        if (get_current_blog() == 2) {
            $noloadplugins = array('w3-total-cache');
            foreach ($plugins as $i => $plugin) {
                 if (in_array($plugin, $noloadplugins)) {unset($plugins[$i]);}
            }
        }
        return $plugins;
    }
}
```

Comment: This also is not working inside a multisite install.  I am attempting to utilize it for the second site in it via `if get_current_blog_id() == 2`, and it still loads and caches everything...

Comment: maybe worth including that in your question... I've added some code for multisite, hopefully does the trick.

Comment: still showing the w3tc comment at the bottom of the pages, and can confirm that it is indeed still caching

Comment: just to check is w3 total cache network activated or just active for that site

Comment: hey @majick  unfortunately W3 Total Cache is Network Activate only. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/h0jugq   Was going to go with Super Cache, but too many errors with the plugin in multi-site and activating on single site alone.

Comment: as mentioned in the update if a plugin is network activated you would have to do something different, probably by using the first method and filter the `active_sitewide_plugins` option instead, and in combination with the `if (get_current_blog == 2)`

Comment: I know... but as I posted, that is not working either

Comment: I've added some example code for that, do you have anything different? if so maybe post it in an update what you have now.

Comment: ...so it actually looks like there are other filters for `get_site_option` (then is now `get_network_option`) so you would need to look at `/wp-includes/option.php` to see whether you need to use the `pre_site_option_{option}` or `default_site_option_{option}` or just `site_option_{option}` filter for your case